# Stability/joinery method for melamine

Tags: joinery, strength

I'm building a book case out of melamine. The drawing below show the normal and exploded view. Dimensions are 110cm wide, 30cm deep, 126cm high (~43"x12"x50")". I'm worried about the stability of it, since it needs to support quite a bit of weight. The white panels are 3cm (1 1/4") thick, the "wooden" panels are 1.9cm (3/4") thick.

I have reinforced the side with steel rods and plan on adding washers and nuts on there (not shown in the drawing) to make the ends more sturdy.

I have a couple of questions:

- In general, do you see any issues with the weight it needs to support? (the largest span is 45cm (17 3/4")). According to what I saw for melamine of this thickness, that should be fine
- Do you see any obvious issues that could cause racking? I added the steel rods to prevent this
- And my biggest issue: In the exploded view, where the red reference line is drawn and the horizontal cross supports connect to the upright support, I'm not sure which type of joinery to use. I don't want to add screws from the outside in. I thought about either dowels or pocket screws, but I'm not sure whether they will be strong enough to support the weight.

[image: book case melamine]

Comment: Sorry, have to check. When you say "melamine" are you referring to chipboard/particleboard with a melamine surface? Can you also please clarify what you mean by stability here. Most woodworkers (I think) are going to assume you're referring to resistance to racking, and/or tipping, when I suspect you're mostly concerned with resistance to sagging? Or is it a bit of both?

Comment: Dowel joints are strong to hugely strong — matching or exceeding both M&Ts (!) and Dominos — so you should have no reservations about using them, if you can get the holes drilled to align accurately (although sloppy fit is no longer an absolute dealbreaker, since we can now restore lost strength by glueing using thickened epoxy). If no external fastening is acceptable they would be my #1 choice here, since the hold of the screws typically used in pocket holes would be an open question... one best not answered in the negative by a problem down the line :-) BTW assuming hardwood dowels here.

Comment: Yes, by melamine I mean particleboard with melamine surface. With stability I mean both racking, tipping and sagging. I think it should be fine, just wanted to see if anyone can spot any weaknesses (rather find out by writing, then by picking up the pieces.) Could you elaborate on "thickened epoxy"? My initial plan would've been to use wood glue.

Comment: With regards to the dowels, I'm not too concerned about the dowels themselves, rather about the dowels breaking through the particle board. The larger diameter dowel I pick, the more that would be a problem. Either way, I think I'd use 4 dowels, both in the cross beams as well as in the shelves

Comment: How are you attaching the shelves to the white cross members? At only 30cm deep, it _could_ tip away from the wall, especially if top heavy and a child or pet were to start climbing it, but, if shimmed vertical (if necessary) probably not on its own. A screw through each upright, just above the top brown shelf (to be hidden by the things in front of it) and into a stud behind should take care of that with no issue.

Comment: I think on the backside I will put screws through the upright and into the cross members as well as into the shelves. The cross member I'll probably attach to the shelves with screws or dowels going from the bottom up into the shelves. I don't really want to attach it to the wall, but yeah, I need to look for a solution of tilting forward.
On the upside, it will probably be bottom heavy, I don't have any children and my french bulldog sucks at climbing :-)

Comment: Have you checked with the sagulator and your intended weight? My gut says that 4' span, books, and 3/4 particleboard will sag over time. Perhaps incorporate a ledger at the back (middle section) in the same 1-1/4" materials? And if your floor isn't dead flat, I imagine you'll have stability problems... consider adjustable feet.

Comment: "I added the steel rods to prevent [racking]" - Not to nitpick, but the steel rods won't add any strength against racking.  To prevent racking you either need supports running from corner-to-corner or joinery wide enough that it won't twist.  In this design the main anti-racking (left-to-right) support would be from how far apart the two dowels are joining the vertical pieces to the top and bottom horizontal pieces.  I would also be very worried about racking front-to-back, which has very little support in this design.  Anchoring it to the wall would prevent this though.

Comment: Thickened epoxy is just epoxy thickened with the addition of a fine powder, nearly anything will do but search here and you'll find more in a previous Answer. PVA-type wood glue is perfectly fine (or polyurethane for that matter) **if** the fit is good. You can't use either though to compensate for a loose or sloppy fit. Thickened epoxy is the glue of choice for most people in this situation. I don't think this will be prone to racking, since the uprights joined to the shelves mutually reinforce. [contd]

Comment: Sagging could be an issue, but it all depends on the specifics — the quality of the material (it's far more varied than one would expect, and the full weight being supported by each shelf. There is obviously a potential for it to tip forwards, as with all tall structures like this, but it's simple to attach the uprights to the wall with tethers to obviate this concern.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, it's not a 4" unsupported span — the Q specifies, the largest unpported span is a mere 17 3/4". Course this still does not mean there's no potential for sag, but my gut says it's not likely unless the books are *unusually* heavy. I've had many particleboard bookshelves in my life and very heavily laden with paperbacks (double stack, double row) an approximate span of 1m does most definitely sag, and this is less than half that.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the detailed answers! Based on the answers I'm going to use dowels for the cross support + shelves into the uprights and add some brackets to attach it to the wall to prevent forward tipping (wanted to avoid that, but better safe than sorry). I'm not worried about sagging since the middle span is 45cm and the outer spans are 21cm (which are also reinforced by the threaded steel rods). Thanks again all!

Comment: Seems like someone aught to gather all the wisdom out of the comments and put it into an answer. Maybe a community wiki answer since so many have contributed.

Comment: (@Graphus) -- my bad! I was skimming and mixed cm/inches. I'll see myself out.

Comment: @FreeMan, that's exactly what I've been trying to allow for these past many months even if the answers-in-comments thing is frowned upon.

Comment: Kenneth, if you include the steel rods then yes absolutely sagging becomes a non-issue for the outside bits (it's actually impossible for them to sag). But something else to be aware of, when you support a shelf structure far in from the ends like this there's a counterbalancing effect, so in effect weight placed outside the supports acts to reduce or prevent sagging in the centre. Although for completeness I have to mention it is still possible for something like particleboard to sag on both sides of the support LOL but honestly, only if the weight is really excessive.

Comment: Re. the potential for this to tip forward, I would not plan at this stage to use any sort of rigid bracket (not least due to installation being awkward to say the least). Build it, put it into its final location and see how it is on the floor there. You could just as easily find it has zero tendency to want to fall forwards as the reverse (I have a couple of spots in the house like that, where there's a very slight dip into the corner so tall shelves actually want to fall into the wall until filled with books). Now if you do find that you need to anchor yours use cloth tethers as per Ikea.